# Is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\dfrac{\cos x-\cos y}{x^2-y^2}$ equal to $-\dfrac 12$ or just $-\dfrac{\sin y}{2y}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Question:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\dfrac{\cos x-\cos y}{x^2-y^2}=?$$
Here is my try:
\begin{align}\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\dfrac{\cos x-\cos y}{x^2-y^2}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\dfrac{-2 \sin (\frac 12(x+y))\sin (\frac{1}{2}(x-y))}{(x+y)(x-y)}\\
&=-\dfrac{2 \sin y}{2y}\dfrac 12\\
&=-\dfrac{\sin y}{2y}\end{align}

My question: Is $-\dfrac{\sin y}{2y}$ the final answer or can it be calculated further as $-\dfrac12$?

---

I also try different route:
Let $p=x-y$ so $x=p+y$ and $p\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow y$. Hence,

\begin{align}\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\dfrac{\cos x-\cos y}{x^2-y^2}&=\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\cos (p+y)-\cos y}{p^2+2py+y^2-y^2}\\\\
&=\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-2 \sin (\frac{1}{2}(p+2y))\sin (\frac{1}{2}p)}{p(p+2y)}\\\\
&=\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-2 \sin (\frac{1}{2}(p+2y))}{(p+2y)} \dfrac{\sin (\frac{1}{2}p)}{p}\\\\
&=-\dfrac{2\sin y}{2y} \dfrac{1}{2}\\\\
&=-\dfrac{\sin y}{2y}\end{align}

Okay, so that left me with the same result. What is the correct final answer, $-\dfrac{\sin y}{2y}$ or $-\dfrac 12$?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it should be $-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Where do you get $-\frac{1}{2}$ from?  Are you computing the limit as $y$ goes to zero?

Comment: There is no reason to believe its $-1/2$, thats only the case if $y$ was approaching zero which it isnt

Comment: You have not shown the derivation for why it should be negative half. Both methods are correct (and up to variables, use the same technique of splitting the cosine), and show the correct answer. It certainly can't be both, so you can be convinced that the answer isn't negative half. You can observe, by taking two explicit values of $y$,that the answer must at least depend on $y$ (or, find a value of $y$ for which the limit isn't negative half).

Comment: Even though this question is labeled "limits-without-l'Hopital," you can use l'Hopital's rule by taking the partial derivatives of the numerator and denominator with respect to $x$ (i.e., keeping $y$ constant).  Then you get $\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\frac{-\sin(x)}{2x}$ and substitution gives you $-\frac{\sin(y)}{2y}$.

Comment: @mrnovice, I asked my math teacher who is now my colleague and he said that the answer is $\dfrac{-1}{2}$ while I believe the answer is $\dfrac{-\sin y}{2y}$. But when I asked for further detail, he admitted that he kind of not sure and asked me to ask someone else.

Comment: @Michael Burr, Sorry for late reply, I lose my internet connection. No, it isn't given that $y$ goes to zero. I just want to make sure what the final answer is. Thanks for the comments. I didn't think that I may use the l'Hopital's rule to get the answer.

Comment: @Ziad Fakhoury, Thanks! Your comment answers my question!

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, Wow, thank you for expalining in comment. It gives me more argument to tell my math teacher!

Comment: @MonicaSendiAfa You are welcome. Also, $+1$ for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also have used Taylor series around $x=y$. This is $$\cos(x)=\cos (y)-(x-y) \sin (y)-\frac{1}{2} (x-y)^2 \cos (y)+O\left((x-y)^3\right)$$ Then $$\cos(x)-\cos (y)=-(x-y) \sin (y)-\frac{1}{2} (x-y)^2 \cos (y)+O\left((x-y)^3\right)$$ $$\frac{\cos(x)-\cos (y) }{x^2-y^2}=-\frac{\sin (y)}{2 y}+(x-y) \left(\frac{\sin (y)}{4 y^2}-\frac{\cos (y)}{4
   y}\right)+O\left((x-y)^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this question is for second grade of senior high school level and I don't think my students would understand if I explain with Taylor Series. Anyway, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @MonicaSendiAfa. You are very welcome ! I think that your students can understand approximation (at least using graphics and no words). If my wife has been able to understand, then I guess that everybody could (don't worry : she stands next to me while I am typing this). Cheers.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I am a new teacher. And greetings to your wife.

Comment: @MonicaSendiAfa. She thanks you (and confirm) ! Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

Your answer is correct. A simpler approach: let $f(x)= \cos x$. Then

$\dfrac{\cos x-\cos y}{x^2-y^2}=\dfrac{f( x)-f(y)}{x-y}* \dfrac{1}{x+y} \to f'(y)* \dfrac{1}{2y}$ for $x \to y$.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this question is for second grade of senior high school level and I still haven't taught my students about Derivative chapter yet. Anyway, I do appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

we know by definition that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\left(\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}\right) = \frac{df}{dy}$$
so the given can be expressed as
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\left(\frac{\cos(x) - \cos(y)}{(x - y)(x + y)}\right)$$
that is equal to
$$\left(\frac{df}{dy}\right)\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\frac{1}{x + y}\right)$$
at last becomes equal to
$$\frac{- sin(y)}{2y}$$